# Configure Kafka client to connect with issued SSL key/cert

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Heroku Kafka, which is running 0.10.1.1 and uses SSL. They only support the latest protocol.

Heroku Kafka uses SSL for authentication and issues and client certificate and key, and provides a CA certificate. I placed these in `client_cert.pem`, `client_key.pem`, and `trusted_cert.pem` respectively, and ran the following to build the keystores:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client_cert.pem -inkey client_key.pem -certfile client_cert.pem -out client.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore kafka.keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
keytool -keystore kafka.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file trusted_cert.pem
```

I then created `client-ssl.properties` containing the following:

```
ssl.protocol=SSL
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.password=xxxx
ssl.keystore.location=kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.password=xxxx
ssl.key.password=xxxx
```

I then use `kafka-console-producer` (version 0.10.1.1) with the following:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list kafka+ssl://a.a.a.a:9096,kafka+ssl://b.b.b.b:9096,kafka+ssl://c.c.c.c:9096 --producer.config client-ssl.properties --topic robintest
```

(The `robintest` topic has been created.)

```
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,385] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka+ssl://a.a.a.a:9096, kafka+ssl://b.b.b.b:9096, kafka+ssl://c.c.c.c:9096]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = console-producer
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 1000
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 1500
    retries = 3
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = kafka.keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = SSL
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = kafka.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,390] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka+ssl://a.a.a.a:9096, kafka+ssl://b.b.b.b:9096, kafka+ssl://c.c.c.c:9096]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = console-producer
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 1000
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 1500
    retries = 3
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = kafka.keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = SSL
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = kafka.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,396] DEBUG Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,398] DEBUG Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,399] DEBUG Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [b.b.b.b:9096 (id: -2 rack: null), c.c.c.c:9096 (id: -3 rack: null), a.a.a.a:9096 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = []) (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name connections-closed: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name connections-created: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name bytes-sent: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,458] DEBUG Added sensor with name bytes-received: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,458] DEBUG Added sensor with name select-time: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,459] DEBUG Added sensor with name io-time: (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,462] DEBUG Added sensor with name batch-size (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,462] DEBUG Added sensor with name compression-rate (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,462] DEBUG Added sensor with name queue-time (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,462] DEBUG Added sensor with name request-time (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,464] DEBUG Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,465] DEBUG Added sensor with name records-per-request (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,465] DEBUG Added sensor with name record-retries (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,465] DEBUG Added sensor with name errors (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,465] DEBUG Added sensor with name record-size-max (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,467] DEBUG Starting Kafka producer I/O thread. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,468] INFO Kafka version : 0.10.1.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,468] INFO Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2017-01-31 10:06:50,468] DEBUG Kafka producer started (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
```

At this point, I send a record and press enter.

```
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,194] DEBUG Initialize connection to node -2 for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,194] DEBUG Initiating connection to node -2 at b.b.b.b:9096. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--2.bytes-sent (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,457] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--2.bytes-received (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,458] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--2.latency (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,460] DEBUG Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 33304, SO_SNDBUF = 102808, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -2 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,463] DEBUG Completed connection to node -2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,692] DEBUG Sending metadata request {topics=[robintest]} to node -2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,724] DEBUG Connection with ec2-34-194-25-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com/b.b.b.b disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,728] DEBUG Node -2 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,728] WARN Bootstrap broker b.b.b.b:9096 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,729] DEBUG Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,729] DEBUG Initiating connection to node -1 at a.a.a.a:9096. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,791] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,792] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,792] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.latency (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,792] DEBUG Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 33304, SO_SNDBUF = 102808, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,792] DEBUG Completed connection to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:53,994] DEBUG Sending metadata request {topics=[robintest]} to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,025] DEBUG Connection with ec2-34-194-39-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com/a.a.a.a disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,026] DEBUG Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,026] WARN Bootstrap broker a.a.a.a:9096 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,027] DEBUG Initialize connection to node -3 for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,027] DEBUG Initiating connection to node -3 at c.c.c.c:9096. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,102] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--3.bytes-sent (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,103] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--3.bytes-received (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,103] DEBUG Added sensor with name node--3.latency (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,104] DEBUG Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 33304, SO_SNDBUF = 102808, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -3 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,104] DEBUG Completed connection to node -3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,309] DEBUG Sending metadata request {topics=[robintest]} to node -3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,342] DEBUG Connection with ec2-34-194-45-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com/c.c.c.c disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,342] DEBUG Node -3 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,343] WARN Bootstrap broker c.c.c.c:9096 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,343] DEBUG Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,343] DEBUG Initiating connection to node -1 at a.a.a.a:9096. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,348] DEBUG Initialize connection to node -2 for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,348] DEBUG Initiating connection to node -2 at b.b.b.b:9096. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,376] DEBUG Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 33304, SO_SNDBUF = 102808, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -2 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,377] DEBUG Completed connection to node -2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,379] DEBUG Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 33304, SO_SNDBUF = 102808, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2017-01-31 10:06:54,379] DEBUG Completed connection to node -1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Those entries go on forever until I terminate the process.

I've tried every combination of configuration, including prefixing all configuration in the properties files with `producer.`, removing the entire configuration (which seems to make no difference), setting the password to an incorrect value (which seems to make no difference). I also tried connecting to a different provider (www.cloudkarafka.com) with their credentials, and I get the same result. So it definitely seems like a configuration problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my Kafka cluster (Heroku add-on) wasn't actually running 0.10.1.1, it was running 0.10.0.1. The two seem to have incompatible consumer APIs. (I have to say, "this is exactly why semantic versioning exists.")

---

To [upgrade Kafka running on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku#upgrading-kafka-versions), use: `heroku kafka:upgrade --version 0.10` *which upgrades to the latest 0.10.X release*. So if you're on 0.9 and you want 0.10.0.1, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, for those coming here having trouble when connecting clients to Kafka on SSL authentication required(`ssl.client.auth`), I found a very helpful snippet [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-ssl-encryption-authentication#client-setup-with-authentication)

```
cd ssl

# Create a java keystore and get a signed certificate for the broker. Then copy the certificate to the VM where the CA is running.

keytool -genkey -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass "MyClientPassword123" -keypass "MyClientPassword123" -dname "CN=mylaptop1" -alias my-local-pc1 -storetype pkcs12

keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -certreq -file client-cert-sign-request -alias my-local-pc1 -storepass "MyClientPassword123" -keypass "MyClientPassword123"

# Copy the cert to the CA
scp client-cert-sign-request3 sshuser@HeadNode0_Name:~/tmp1/client-cert-sign-request

# Switch to the CA machine (hn0) to sign the client certificate.
cd ssl
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in /tmp1/client-cert-sign-request -out /tmp1/client-cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:MyServerPassword123

# Return to the client machine (hn1), navigate to ~/ssl folder and copy signed cert from the CA (hn0) to client machine
scp -i ~/kafka-security.pem sshuser@HeadNode0_Name:/tmp1/client-cert-signed

# Import CA cert to trust store
keytool -keystore kafka.client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "MyClientPassword123" -keypass "MyClientPassword123" -noprompt

# Import CA cert to key store
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "MyClientPassword123" -keypass "MyClientPassword123" -noprompt

# Import signed client (cert client-cert-signed1) to keystore
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -import -file client-cert-signed -alias my-local-pc1 -storepass "MyClientPassword123" -keypass "MyClientPassword123" -noprompt
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice this ( your making your truststore and keystore )...

```
openssl **pkcs12** -export
```

But yet in kafka config you have...

```
ssl.truststore.type=**JKS**
```

Is there a conflict there?

Reason I say that is I made a pkcs12 truststore and I did not config for ssl.truststore.type ( never added the line to config ).

I see I get this...

> 2018-04-13 19:45:04,495 [main] ERROR c.my.special.package.MyApp  : Exception occured starting the SpecialConsumer 
>   java.io.IOException: **Invalid keystore format**